# how change the play IconButton when the audio is Completed playing

Tags: android, dart, flutter

how to make the IconButton icon change when the audio has finished playing

Answer (score 1):

I am showing a simple code which mocks a music being played for 10 seconds and then stops after that and Icon changes

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(home: SOM());
    /*
    return MaterialApp(initialRoute: 'home', routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{
      'home': (context) => SOMain(),
      '/secondPage': (context) => DefaultScaffold("Second Screen", SOSecond()),
      '/thirdPage': (context) => DefaultScaffold("Third Screen", SOThird()),
    });

     */
  }
}

class SOM extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SOMState createState() => _SOMState();
}

class _SOMState extends State<SOM> {
  bool isPlaying = false;

  IconData musicIcon = Icons.play_arrow;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
          child: IconButton(
        icon: Icon(musicIcon),
        onPressed: toggleMusic,
      )),
    );
  }

  void toggleMusic() {
    if (!isPlaying) {
      startPlayingMusic();
    }
  }

  void startPlayingMusic() {
    setState(() {
      isPlaying = true;
      musicIcon = Icons.pause;
    });

//    faking music play for 10 seconds

    Timer(Duration(seconds: 10), () {
      setState(() {
        isPlaying = false;
        musicIcon = Icons.play_arrow;
      });
    });
  }
}
```

Note: The current working does not change states if music is already playing, it just play mocks music play for 10s after button click and ends. Nothing else.

Comment: new code shows mock behaviour of music play for 10 seconds

Answer (score 0):

Create PlayerEvents like this:

```
enum PlayerEvent {
  onStartPlaying, onStopPlaying, onPausePlaying
}
```

And create a BLoC like this:

```
final playerBloc = PlayerBloc();

class PlayerBloc {
  StreamController<PlayerEvent> _playerEventStreamController = StreamController.broadcast();

  Stream<PlayerEvent> get playerEventStream => _playerEventStreamController.stream;

  dispatch(PlayerEvent event) {
    _playerEventStreamController.sink.add(event);
  }


  dispose(){
    _playerEventStreamController.close();
  }
}
```

Wrap your icon with stream builder like this:

```
StreamBuilder<PlayerEvent>(
    stream: playerBloc.playerEventStream,
    initialData: PlayerEvent.onStopPlaying,
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
        switch(snapshot.data) {
            case PlayerEvent.onStopPlaying:
                return Icon(Icons.play_arrow);
            case PlayerEvent.onStartPlaying:
                return Icon(Icons.pause);
            case PlayerEvent.onPausePlaying:
                return Icon(Icons.play_arrow);
        }
    }
),
```

Now whenever your music starts or stops playing just call this:

```
playerBloc.dispatch(PlayerEvent.onStartPlaying);
```

or

```
playerBloc.dispatch(PlayerEvent.onStopPlaying);
```

and your icons will change as per your music.